# vue js use v-on within watch method

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have a component that has a data property called rows, which are used to populate a dynamic table (I'm using Datatables). 
I have a computed property called clientLeads that loads store data. 
I have a watch function that watches the clientLeads computed property and updates the rows data property.

I would like to use the router-link component to create a Vue JS Router link to a profile page.

Here is the Datatables component (src: https://codepen.io/stwilson/pen/oBRePd):

```
<script>
import 'datatables.net-bs4'
import jQuery from 'jquery'

export default {
  template: '<table class="table table-striped dt-responsive nowrap" style="width:100%"></table>',
  props: {
    headers: {
      default () {
        return {}
      }
    },
    rows: {
      default () {
        return []
      }
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      dTHandle: null
    }
  },
  watch: {
    rows (val, oldVal) {
      let vm = this
      vm.dtHandle.clear()
      vm.dtHandle.rows.add(vm.rows)
      vm.dtHandle.draw()
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    let vm = this
    vm.dtHandle = jQuery(this.$el).DataTable({
      classes: {
        sWrapper: 'dataTables_wrapper dt-bootstrap4'
      },
      columns: vm.headers,
      data: vm.rows,
      searching: false,
      paging: false,
      info: true,
      responsive: {
        details: {
          type: 'column'
        }
      }
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

And here is my view component:

```
<template> 
    <div>
        <data-tables :headers="headers" :rows="rows" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            headers: [
                { title: 'Name' },
                { title: '&nbsp;' }
            ],
            rows: []
        }
    },
    computed: mapGetters({
        clientLeads: 'clientLeads'
    }),
    watch: {
        clientLeads (val, oldVal) {
            let vm = this
            let rows = []
            val.forEach(function (item) {
                let row = []
                row.push(item.name)
                row.push('<router-link to="/lead_details/' + item.id + '"><a><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a></router-link>')
                rows.push(row)
            })
            vm.rows = rows
        }
    },
    created () {
        // get leads
        this.$store.dispatch('getClientLeads', {
            status: this.status
        })
    }
}
</script>
```

However, the resulting html is:

```
<router-link to="/lead_details/123"><a><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a></router-link>
```

...instead of:

```
<a href="/lead_details/123"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
```

I understand why but cannot figure out a workaround to resolve my issue.

Comment: what does your table html look like?

Comment: It's dynamically built by a datatables component. Are you asking what the resulting table should look like?

    <data-tables :headers="headers" :rows="rows" />

Comment: I don't know this `datatables` component but usually in this case you would only push the route url in your row data then use a slot in your component template to define a template for a specific column or cell (depending on the datatables component implementation). If you provide a jsfiddle maybe we could look for a solution.

Comment: @budgw - The datatables component is a custom component based on work by Will Vincent (https://codepen.io/stwilson/pen/oBRePd). I have been using DataTables (datatables.net) for years and prefer to keep using it. I have updated my question w/ the source code of the very simple datatables component in hopes it will help you understand better.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `datatables` manipulates the DOM outside of Vue.js. As Vue doesn't handle the elements created by the lib, the router link component is not 'interpreted'.

If you want to keep going with this datables library maybe you can try to add a standard `<a>` tag with a # prefixed href :

```
<a href="#/lead_details/123"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
```

As vue-router seems to prefix url with a # when you are in the default mode (hash-mode) : https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations. Or you can just change the mode to `history` :

```
const router = new VueRouter({
   mode: 'history',
   routes: [...]
 })
```

And get rid of the #.
Of course it supposes you have the matching route declared previously. It's a little tweaky as you will bypass vue-router like this and reload the page, but it works.

Working with vue, I strongly recommend, as much as possible, to prefered libraries that doesn't manipulate directly the DOM and let this task to Vue. Vue components give more options to be tweaked.
There are many components libraries that seems to do the job, for example : 
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables
or http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table

Comment: Yes; like I said, I understand why this is not working for me. My router setup already uses the history method and I have been utilizing an anchor until I find a better solution but I was really hoping there was some work around that would not involve reloading the page. That being said, I appreciate your answer and might even consider the element table as a viable option. Thank you.